# bulk photo editor

Tags: windows-7, photo-editing

Is there an application that would allow me to just drug in a bunch of icons and change the color of those icons to pure gray.I really want to make my desktop look like this:
http://www.howtogeek.com/news/this-customized-windows-desktop-has-impressive-icons/190/
but I need to customize all of the icons so that there is harmony in color.
As much as possible I do not want to use photoshop for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Irfanview's batch mode?

http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/graphics/irfantut/imagmenu.html#conve

Answer (score 2):

How about [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)? That can perform bulk operations either from a [command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)/batch file, or with a scripting language like [perl](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) or [vbscript](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php).